# Unmerged branch in Git

Tags: git

I am using Git, had created a branch named logging, did a bunch of changes, got code reviewed and then pushed them upstream. Now, our main developer after review merged the branch. But after some time he found conflicts and had to unmerge the branch. Now, I am screwed. The upstream branch logging still exists. How do I create a new branch with all the changes that I did in the logging branch and push it out for code review etc. Please advise.

Comment: I don't quite get what you want to achieve.  Did your _main developer_ unmerge on his repo?  Can't you just clone / fetch it again after you reset your repo to before the merge?

Answer (score 0):

Try use:

```
git checkout develop
git merge logging
```

Comment: That does not seem to be working. Ok I have multiple commits in the logging branch. Can't I cherry pick all those commits from the logging branch into a new branch. And then rebase it with master etc. Please advise.

Comment: you need cherry pick one by one to bring it to a unique branch, them merge that branch... Try it, them lets see

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's what I did. I cherry picked and applied it to a brand new branch that I created from development.

And then resolved merge conflicts. This works! Here are the steps:
**Cherry-Picking**
- Create a new branch from development
- Apply cherry pick a particular commit from another branch to this branch
- Do a git status
- Fix all the merge conflicts and run
- Git cherry-pick - - continue